# SwiftUI - cannot find type 'UIApplicationDelegate' in scope

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am new to MacOS development and Swift so sorry if this is a basic/stupid question.

I am getting this error:

```
Cannot find type 'UIApplicationDelegate' in scope
```

I have created an `AppDelegate.swift` file to try to define a default window size for my app. I have this code:

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: ContentView())
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
}
```

I'm not really sure what to do here. Is there something I need to import?

Thnak you for your help.

Comment: For macOS you need to use `NSApplicationDelegate`.

Comment: @pawello2222 thanks, that worked. But now I am getting "consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'". XCode's suggestion is to replace `window.x()` with `window;.x()`. What should I do about that?

Comment: Do you have a chance to start over? Using Xcode 12.4, a new macOS "App" project takes you to a second screen where, if you choose "SwiftUI" as the interface and "AppKit App Delegate" as the Life Cycle, looks like it creates all necessary files. (Including your original issue - AppDelegate.swift.)

Comment: @dfd okay, I've done that now, and it works as expected. Thankfully I hadn't started my project at all, so it was fine to start over.

Comment: Glad to help. I'm more versed in iOS, but I took a chance. Starting in Xcode 12, Apple (at least for iOS) added a way for a SwiftUI project to not use AppDelegate and SceneDelegate. I'm guessing when you created your macOS project you had the wrong selection for "Life Cycle".

Comment: @dfd yes, that was my exact issue. My thought process was literally "which one looks the least weird?" which was not the best thing in hindsight. Thank you, that was very helpful

Answer (score -6):

import FBSDKCoreKit. This will help u :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).